# "chrome: no process found" while installing linux-ntizen

Tags: dpkg

When I typed `apt-get install upgrade`, I got error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up linux-netizen (1.0.1-1) ...
chrome: no process found
dpkg: error processing linux-netizen (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
     linux-netizen
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I tried some method to fix it:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install --configure -a
```

But all methods are not working. Please help me....

Comment: Run these commands on terminal, `sudo apt-get hold linux-netizen` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: @AvinashRaj There is no such operation `apt-get hold`

Comment: Sorry. Its apt-mark hold.

Comment: @karel: No, this is not about unmet dependencies.

Comment: Please add the contents of the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-netizen.postinst` to your question.

Answer (score -1):

First remove the package:

```
sudo dpkg -r linux-netizen
```

Then remove the package's entry in dpkg status file :

So run

```
gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Then search and remove the whole section starts with `Package: linux-netizen`

Then Upgrade.